# Minecraft Bukkit - Detect if player is running command from a sign

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I am trying to write a command that is supposed to teleport a player if **(a)** the player is running it by clicking a sign *and* **(b)** other conditions are met. This is what I have so far for my `CommandExecutor` `onCommand` function:

```java
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("ERROR: You must be a player to use this command.");
            return true;
        }
        if (sender.hasPermission(permission) && /* Other conditions */) { // permission is given as an argument to the command
            ((Player) sender).teleport(new Location(world, destX, destY, destZ, destYw, destPt)); // These variables are all determined based on the arguments to the command.
            return true;
        }
        return true;
}
```

This allows any player to teleport anywhere by typing `/<name of my custom command>` and using a permission that they have, such as `group.default` (for [LuckPerms](https://luckperms.net/)). I don't want players to be able to use my command to do this.

In contrast, on an unmodded Minecraft server, if you give yourself a sign using

```text
/give @s minecraft:oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{front_text:{messages:['{"text":"","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"tp @s 0 100 0"}}','{"text":"MySign"}','{"text":"Select to teleport.","italic":true,"color":"white"}','{"text":""}']},is_waxed:1b}}
```

then anyone (i.e., people without op) can click the sign to teleport to (0, 100, 0), but they cannot run `/tp 0 100 0` or `/tp <anything>` in the chat.

**How do I accomplish this behavior with my custom Bukkit command?** Is there a way to detect whether a player is running a command by right-clicking a sign (and then return without teleporting if they are not), or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. The CommandSender will not be the player but a block?

Answer (score 0):

With this sign

```
/give @s minecraft:oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{front_text:{messages:['{"text":"","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"tp @s 0 100 0"}}','{"text":"MySign"}','{"text":"Select to teleport.","italic":true,"color":"white"}','{"text":""}']},is_waxed:1b}}
```

The **server** executes the command */tp @s 0 100 0*, thats why the players can click the sign even tho they dont have the permisson to run the */tp* command.

I think the best way to do this is to listen to the PlayerInteractEvent in a Bukkit Listener instead of a command.

This is how to teleport the Player when they interact with a sign:

```
@EventHandler
public void OnInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event)
{
   if(event.getClickedBlock().getState() instanceof Sign)
   {
       //When the player clicked on a Sign

        event.getPlayer().teleport(........);
    }
}
```

I hope this helped you!

Comment: As an addition: You can always pass a extra argument to your command that you can only send with a special permission. The server will only allow this argument if it comes from the server, and if it does, you know its because it was executed from a sign-